# Can Vue.js generate a real time event based on the current Date?

Tags: mongodb, express, vue.js

I want to create real-time notifications in a Vue.Js application. My goal is to get a notifications when the deadline of a post exceeds based on the current date.

I hope I can achieve this by setting the setInteval periodically to get the Date and reload the page.

But this is not a pleasant development. I want to communicate with the backend real time like the Socket or Pusher do.

I am ready to do it in Vue.Js alone if I am able to do so (ex: using computed, watch etc ..)

Thank you for reading the long question. Have a nice day.'

**except**

```
...
<template slot-scope="props">
  <b-datepicker v-model:props.row.deadline>
  </b-datepicker>
  <div v-if="now<props.row.deadline">
    deadline Over!
  </div>
  <div v-else>
    {{props.row.deadline}}
  </div>
</templates>

...

<script>
...
  date () {
    return {
      posts: {},
      now: new Date(),
    }
  }
...
</script>
...
```

Comment: This is unclear: do you want to do something at a certain time, or do you want to do something in response to a serverside event? The two have very different answers.

Comment: I already have data in the vue via api. I would welcome if it could be handled at the front end rather than at the server end like pusher or socket.

Comment: If I am understanding correctly, you need to set a timeout till the time you want, then set a value in your model; display your notification with `v-if`. No need for reloading.

Comment: The deadline field is already stored. I do not know where to generate the current time data. Do you create and compare new Date () periodically?

Comment: And even if v-if does not appear when the page is reloaded? Please tell me if I'm wrong!

Comment: I still don't understand you. Can you state exactly what you want to do? What is "the deadline field"? Where is it stored? What do you mean by "generate the current time data", and why would you need it? `v-if` shows or hides an element based on a condition, why would reloading have anything to do with it? Rather than continue in comments, I suggest you edit your question and add as much details about _exactly_ what you want to do, preferably with code samples, and especially with sample data.

Comment: Thank you. As you said, I've added the code I want.

Comment: I would like to implement real-time functionality automatically in applications through now.

Comment: Again, if I understand correctly, `setInterval(() => app.now = new Date(), 1000)` should solve your problem. This way `v-if="now<props.row.deadline"` should be checked (and the associated element updated) every second (or however often you desire).

Comment: I tried to use setInteval in the create hook, but it is not constantly monitored.